# Extracting Highlighted Words from Word Document (.docx) in Python

Tags: python, xml, ms-word, docx

I am working with a bunch of word documents in which I have text (words) that are highlighted (using color codes e.g. yellow,blue,gray), now I want to extract the highlighted words associated with each color. I am programming in Python. Here is what I have done currently:

opened the word document with `[python-docx][1]` and then get to the `<w:r>` tag which contains the tokens (words) in the document. I have used following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
# -*- coding: ascii -*-
from docx import *
document = opendocx('test.docx')
words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)
for word in words:
  print word
```

Now I am stuck at the part where I check for each word if it has `<w:highlight>` tag and extract the color code from it and if it matches to yellow print text inside `<w:t>` tag. I will really appreciate if someone can point me towards extracting the word from the parsed file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had never before worked with [python-docx](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx), but what helped was that I found a snippet online of how the XML structure of a highlighted piece of text lookls like:

```
 <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
      <w:highlight w:val="yellow"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>text that is highlighted</w:t>
  </w:r>
```

From there, it was relatively straightforward to come up with this:

```
from docx import *
document = opendocx(r'test.docx')
words = document.xpath('//w:r', namespaces=document.nsmap)

WPML_URI = "{http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main}"
tag_rPr = WPML_URI + 'rPr'
tag_highlight = WPML_URI + 'highlight'
tag_val = WPML_URI + 'val'

for word in words:
    for rPr in word.findall(tag_rPr):
        if rPr.find(tag_highlight).attrib[tag_val] == 'yellow':
            print word.find(tag_t).text
```

Comment: I made some minor changes (missing declaration of tag_t and the handling of ascii to utf8 characters) the revised code is available at https://gist.github.com/1982168 once again thanks @BioGeek!

Comment: You're welcome. It was a cool question and I learned something new as well. Greetings from a fellow bioinformatician!