# Finding a heading in word file and copying entire paragraph thereafter to new word file with python

Tags: python, list, csv, ms-word, docx

I have the following situation:

I have several hundred word files that contain company information. I would like to search these files for specific words to find specific paragraphs and copy just these paragraphs to new word files. Basically I just need to reduce the original couple hundred documents to a more readable size each.

The documents that I have are located in one directory and carry different names. In each of them I want to extract particular information that I need to define individually.

To go about this I started with the following code to first write all file names into a .csv file:

```
# list all transcript files and print names to .csv

import os
import csv

with open("C:\\Users\\Stef\\Desktop\\Files.csv", 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk("C:\\Users\\Stef\\Desktop\\Files"):
        for filename in files:
            writer.writerow([filename])
```

This works perfectly. Next I open Files.csv and edit the second column for the keywords that I need to search for in each document.

See picture below for how the .csv file looks:

[CSV file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysiq5.jpg)

The couple hundred word files I have, are structured with different layers of headings. What I wanted to do now was to search for specific headings with the keywords I manually defined in the .csv and then copy the content of the following passage to a new file. I uploaded an extract from a word file, "Presentation" is a 'Heading 1' and "North America" and "China" are 'Heading 2'.

[Word example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls7f2.jpg)

In this case I would like for example to search for the 'Headline 2' "North America" and then copy the text that is below ("In total [...] diluted basis.) to a new word file that has the same name as the old one just an added "_clean.docx".

I started with my code as follows:

```
import os
import glob
import csv
import docx

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Stef\\Desktop')

f = open('Files.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

file_name = []
matched_keyword = []

for row in csv_f:
  file_name.append(row[0])
  matched_keyword.append(row[1])

filelist = file_name
filelist2 = matched_keyword

for i, j in zip(filelist, filelist2):
  rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\Stef\\Desktop\\Files'
  doc = docx.Document(os.path.join(rootdir, i))
```

After this I was not able to find any working solution. I tried a few things but could not succeed at all. I would greatly appreciate further help.

I think the end should then again look something like this, however not quite sure.

```
output = 
output.save(i +"._clean.docx")
```

Have considered the following questions and ideas:

[Extracting MS Word document formatting elements along with raw text information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114861/extracting-ms-word-document-formatting-elements-along-with-raw-text-information)

[extracting text from MS word files in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125222/extracting-text-from-ms-word-files-in-python)

[How can I search a word in a Word 2007 .docx file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116139/how-can-i-search-a-word-in-a-word-2007-docx-file?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Just figured something similar for myself, so here is a complete working example for you. Might be a more pythonic way of doing it…

```
from docx import Document

inputFile = 'soTest.docx'
try:
    doc = Document(inputFile)
except:
    print(
        "There was some problem with the input file.\nThings to check…\n"
        "- Make sure the file is a .docx (with no macros)"
    )
    exit()

outFile = inputFile.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0] + "_clean.docx"

strFind = 'North America'
# paraOffset used in the event the paragraphs are not adjacent
paraOffset = 1
# document.paragraph returns a list of objects
parasFound = []
paras = doc.paragraphs
# use the list index find the paragraph immediately after the known string
# keep a list of found paras, in the event there is more than 1 match
parasFound = [paras[index+paraOffset] 
                for index in range(len(paras))
                if (paras[index].text == strFind)]

# Add paras to new document
docOut = Document()
for para in parasFound:
    docOut.add_paragraph(para.text)

docOut.save(outFile)
exit()
```

I've also added a image of the input file, showing that North America appears in more than 1 place. [image: Test Word File]